# AWS - Send Scheduled Events notifications with text message or HipChat message

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I know that the AWS sends emails about any EC2 instances with [Scheduled Events](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/monitoring-instances-status-check_sched.html), but I would also like to have these notifications sent through HipChat and text message as well.  Is there a default way of selecting a setting that can do this in AWS?  Or would I have to create a more custom solution to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Scheduled Events in EC2 being [manual tool for monitoring health](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/monitoring_automated_manual.html#monitoring_manual_tools) of instances as of right now, there isn't many options. From the design point of view on AWS platform, this could be one possible solution:

- Create AWS SES mailbox and enable it to receive emails,
- Create a forwarding rule in your original e-mail inbox where you receive those e-mail notifications from AWS about [Scheduled Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/monitoring-instances-status-check_sched.html) to forward e-mails of this type (based on filter you define) to the previously created AWS SES mailbox,
- In your AWS SES mailbox create ["Receipt Rule" with SNS Action](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email-action-sns.html), that will basically publish entire content of the e-mail to the SNS Topic using AWS SNS. (The SNS topic you choose must be in the same AWS region as the Amazon SES endpoint you use to receive email)
- Once that e-mail content lands in AWS SNS Topic as an event, you can use [AWS Lambda subscribed to your SNS topic](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-lambda-as-subscriber.html) as a handler of the event, parse what you need and forward customized notification to any of your third-party (outside of AWS) alerting tools (such as PagerDuty, Slack channel, HipChat, or whatever you use for SMS notifications).

This design does have one week point: relying onto your external mailbox forwarding system (if you are receiving Scheduled Events e-mails in inbox not based on AWS SES).

Ideally you could try to see in your [AWS Account settings](https://console.aws.amazon.com/billing/home?#/account) if it is possible to use AWS SES mailbox for Scheduled Events notifications, but I haven't tried that.

Answer (score -2):

You can receive text messages as notification by setting alarm for that ec2 instance e.g if CPU usages goes above 80% then create an alarm and eventually you can set it to get emails or text messages. Thanks

Comment: That could be a solution. I know `cloud watch` can monitor metrics such as CPU utilization, Memory, Disk I/O and network stuff.  However I'm not sure if it can monitor the presence of a pending Scheduled Event.

Comment: This doesn't really provide solution to the original problem @AlexCohen. Those are EC2 instance metrics and events that are originated by the EC2 instance performance, and not Scheduled Events that are triggered by AWS maintenance teams.